# call_user_func_array no retorna valor

Tags: php, php7

Estoy elaborando un script en PHP y me encuentro con este problema cuando uso `call_user_func` todo marcha bien retorna el valor de la función como he establecido, pero si uso `call_user_func_array` no me retorna el valor correcto. ¿Alguna idea de a qué se deba?

El código trabaja con una clase con funciones/métodos estáticos `static` y hace referencia a una variable interna igual `static` de un modo similar a esto:

```
class ControlURL {

    private static $url = 'Valor de variable';

    public static function set($url){

        static::$url = $url;

    }
    public static function get() {

        return static::$variable;

    }

}
```

Pero al momento de hacer esto:

```
// Establecer URL
call_user_func(['ControlURL','set'],'index');

// Saber la URL funciona bien!
echo call_user_func(['ControlURL','get']);

// Este no funciona
echo call_user_func_array(['ControlURL','get']);
```

Repito solo `call_user_func` me retorna el valor, mientras que la otra solo devuelve `NULL`

Comment: Si agregas lo que llevas al momento entonces tu pregunta tienes mas oportunidades de ser mejor recibida

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi pregunta, espero poder encontrar alguna respuesta. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Y que tiene de malo usar la primera forma? La segunda es necesaria solamente cuando quieres invocar un método de instancia y no de clase

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el contexto y el código real que estás usando, incluyendo el valor de `$arg`? A mi me retorna el valor en los dos casos.